# Gtk Grab pointer without "stealing" it from other software

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Currently in my application I'm grabing the pointer to know when user clicks outside of some of my first window's widgets to hide my second window. Unfortunately if I grab the pointer then user needs to click outside of my application twice to set focus on another window.

When window gets focus I grab the pointer:

```
this.focus_in_event.connect(()=>{
            var pointer = Gdk.Display.get_default ().get_device_manager ().get_client_pointer ();
            pointer.grab (this.get_window (), Gdk.GrabOwnership.NONE, true, 
                   Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK, null, Gdk.CURRENT_TIME);

            Gtk.device_grab_add (this, pointer, false);
            return false;
});
```

When a click events occurs and some of window's widgets didn't 'lock' the pointer:

```
this.button_press_event.connect ( ()=>{

            if (!lock_mouse_click) {
                var pointer = Gdk.Display.get_default ().get_device_manager ().get_client_pointer ();
                Gtk.device_grab_remove (this, pointer);
                pointer.ungrab (Gdk.CURRENT_TIME);

                feed_view.hide ();
            }

            lock_mouse_click = false;
            return false;
});
```

What I would like to do is to "peek" at the pointer instead of stealing the mouse events outside of my application.

My code in vala but you may answer me in any language that uses gtk.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use "enter-notify-signal" ? when apointer enter your widget's window, create a on/off switch somewhere and use it in "button-press-signal". if its on when button is pressed do somethin, if its off do something else